# $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$,$A=FG^*$ and $r(A)=r(F)=r(G)$. Prove $A^\dagger = G(F^*AG)^{-1}F^*$ and $A^\dagger = (G^\dagger)^*F^\dagger$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, generalized-inverse

Let $A^\dagger$ be a Moore-Penrose inverse of a matrix $A$.

If $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ and $A=FG^*$, for some $F,G$ and $r(A)=r(F)=r(G)$, prove that
$$A^\dagger = G(F^*AG)^{-1}F^*$$ and $$A^\dagger = (G^\dagger)^*F^\dagger.$$

I need to show this using SVD decomposition and maybe some other properties of a Moore-Penrose inverse.

I tried to show the statement by writing SVD decomposition of all the matrices included, but it just gets messy and I didn't succeed.

Any hints would be really helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do we know the sizes of $F$ and $G$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, they can be of any size, $F \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times p}$ and $G \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times p}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both equalities are technically false. The first one is false because in general, $F^\ast AG$ is not necessarily non-singular. For the second one, it is easy to generate a random counterexample when $F,G$ are "fat" matrices with more columns than rows.

However, both equalities are true when $F$ and $G$ are "tall" matrices of full column ranks and of the same sizes. In this case, we have $(F^\ast AG)^{-1}=(F^\ast FG^\ast G)^{-1}=(G^\ast G)^{-1}(F^\ast F)^{-1}$ and $F^\dagger F=G^\dagger G=I$. Now you can easily prove that $A^\dagger=G(G^\ast G)^{-1}(F^\ast F)^{-1}F^\ast=(G^\dagger)^\ast F^\dagger$ by verifying the [four defining properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) of Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse directly.

Comment: Where did you use the information about the ranks? Doesn't that maybe change the fact that $F^*AG$ is not always non-singular? I'm not sure that it does, but that information should be used. And also, I just wanted to say that $F^*AG$ is always well-defined because of $A=FG^*$.

Comment: @mathbbandstuff You are right that $F^\ast AG$ is well defined. The ranks conditions are used, as said in the answer: $F^\ast AG$ is always non-singular when $F$ and $G$ have **full column ranks**, but not so otherwise. E.g. $F^\ast AG=1$ is nonsingular when $F=G=\pmatrix{1\\ 0}$, but $F^\ast AG=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$ is singular when $F=G=\pmatrix{1&0}$. In both cases $F,G$ and $A$ are rank-1 matrices.